# Where do I put this helper function, in the model or post_helper or?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All my controllers inherit from applicatin_controller.rb, and I added:

helper :all

I want to use this function in my view to make url's like:

/post/some-title

instead of using the ID int he url

```
def post_path_for(post)
    post_path(:id => post.title_parameterize)
end
```

This is rails 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use it.
If it's in helper, you could call `<%= post_path_for post %>` in your view.
If it's in model, with small change you could call it like this: `<%= post.path %>`

Although second way is shorter, I usually put such functions in helpers, for the sake of separation of logic and presentation.

Comment: You should use to_param though ;)

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use "to_param" in your model to change that without having to write a helper?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nikita. It sounds like a helper to me. I use helpers for anything that is meant for display. It sounds like you want this available to all views. If that is the case, I would place it in helpers/application_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Robin's `to_param` method. By using `to_param`, you could use the built-in url helpers (like `link_to`, `url_for`, ...natively)

For the other point, you mentioned you put it in controller and wanted to use it in view. You need the following line:

```
helper_method :post_path_for
```